# Are mouthparts best placed on the head or the mouth?

Tags: anatomy, food

Let there be a creature with mammalian dentition, with three types of teeth among its jaws. Its mouth, however, is in its stomach.

Should this creature have its jaws on its head, or on its mouth? Or would it make sense to split the jaws, with certain teeth on the head and others on the mouth? I am referring to which arrangement is the most biodynamically favorable in terms of processing its food. Assume the creature is a generalist omnivore that consumes animals, plants, or other creatures at its convenience.

Comment: You can have multiple jaws with full sets of teeth, don't let anyone tell you otherwise.

Comment: @biziclop Wouldn't that be redundant?

Comment: Maybe but that's not how nature works.

Comment: @biziclop What do you mean?

Comment: We've still got claw retractor muscles for example (well, some of us do), we've still got muscles that are supposed to move our ears and all the nerve circuitry that goes with it and so on. The idea that evolution is a perfect optimiser is observably incorrect.

Comment: Or, to stay with teeth, we've all got wisdom teeth.

Comment: @IchthysKing You have two eyes, ears, hands, and in particular lungs and kidneys. Are those redundant? Maybe. But having only one might reduce performance and might mean the difference between life and death in some cases.

Comment: Some species of bony fishes, such as the [moray eels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moray_eel) have [two sets of jaws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharyngeal_jaw), one set at the front to grab the prey, and one deep in the phrarynx, *Alien*-style, used to crush or slice the prey.

Comment: @AlexP But both are around the moray's mouth

Comment: You need to to do a better job of describing this creature, how does is have a jaw separate from its mouth? I think you are confused about something  the head evolved after the mouth, it evolved to concentrate all the sense organs around the mouth. chewing in the gut is a thing though look at gizzards.

Comment: Please look at the language you are using - "It [sic] mouth, however, is in its stomach" - seems to be interpreted by some people as "the mouth is in the abdomen" ie where the stomach is located in many creatures and by others as "the mouth is inside the stomach" ie the mouth is inside the organ used for initial digestion.  Neither interpretation makes sense for any definition of "mouth" that I can find, so I suggest you clarify - are you referring to "mouth" as "place where teeth are"?

Comment: @biziclop evolution is an optimizer, but it has the caveats of “do we realize what exactly it’s optimized for” and “it takes time for no longer necessary parts to evolve out of the genes”. Your example of the retractor muscles could simply be that its a necessary part to get other muscles to grow in the right place at the right time with the right shape. And having an alternative scheme without those retractor muscles might not be feasible for evolution to achieve (yet).

Comment: @Demigan That's fair, yes. Change itself often has a cost.

Comment: I have no idea what it means to have jaws in the head but a mouth in the stomach. A picture would help.

Comment: This question could easily be improved by careful consideration and usage of prepositions! What do you mean by "on" the head? "On" the mouth? Might also want to clarify "in the stomach". I'll VTR once clarified!

Comment: Why would you have jaws without a mouth? Granted, teeth have been known to grow [on a creature's head](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/idaho-mountain-lion-found-with-teeth-growing-out-of-the-top-of-its-head-a6806856.html), [inside the brain](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-2569243/Baby-fully-formed-teeth-growing-inside-BRAIN-rare-tumour.html) and [elsewhere](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4678266/), but are you asking about that? Is the "mouth" you're asking about only for breathing (aka nostrils...)? This question is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, "making sense" is not really a priority of evolution. In fact evolution rarely results in something that is no longer needed for survival disappearing completely. Humans are full of largely redundant features, from claw retractor muscles (palmaris longus), through nictitating membranes to wisdom teeth. Whales have fingerbones.

The reason for this is that evolution is just a kind of gradient descent, if one variant doesn't cost more in numbers of surviving offspring than the other, the switch  will happen very slowly, if it happens at all. The less the pressure, the slower the change.

That being said, omnivore teeth by and large serve 3 main food-related purposes:

1. **Grabbing.** This isn't just for grabbing prey, it's also needed for tearing off chunks of anything that doesn't fit into the mouth whole.
2. **Chopping.** Roughly speaking this is about cutting your food into chunks small enough to move further down the digestive tract.
3. **Grinding.** Exposing more surface area for the digestive juices.

This is a massive oversimplification of course but even from this you can see that realistically only the third function can migrate further down the digestive tract, the first two need to stay near the entry point.

So even in an "optimised" creature you'd want to keep your incisors and canines in your mouth and your molar type teeth can move further down.

In fact such a creature already exists: crocodiles only use their teeth for grabbing and tearing, grinding is done in a specialised stomach called gizzard. Although they don't have teeth in it, they do swallow stones and other hard objects that get embedded in its wall and grind the food down. *(Sadly they're the only kind of reptile to have them, so there's no such thing as a lizard gizzard.)*

Comment: But should the chopping/grabbing mouthparts be around the mouth, or should they be on the head at the front of the body?

Comment: @IchthysKing How do you imagine grabbing prey with your stomach to work? :)

Comment: what about chopping mouthparts? Are they better place at the mouth or on the front of the head?

Comment: @IchthysKing Again, the idea of chopping, as I say in the answer, is to make it possible to swallow the food. So you'd want it somewhere before the digestive tract starts moving food via peristaltic motion. In our case that bit is the mouth.

Comment: But could it make sense for the chopping parts to be before the mouth?

Comment: @IchthysKing - Not really - because you need to chop the food up into small enough pieces to fit down the esophagus. We can't inhale a whole steak, we aren't snakes. If you change the physiology enough that we are snake-like in that we swallow our prey whole, then perhaps - but even Snakes have teeth in their mouth for Grabbing, so...

Comment: As I understand it, birds of prey use their beaks to tear prey into chunks and don't have teeth; I don't know if you'd consider that a "chopping part before the mouth".

Comment: Wait... @IchthysKing ... are you imagining a creature where the part of the path from the head to the stomach we humans call the mouth... *is at the opening to the stomach?* So, when the creature closes it's mouth, water could fall through the head orifice until it reaches the lips at the outskirts of the stomach? That design would allow the question to make sense... other than the creature would drown when it rains.